# Soccorro server does not work

Tags: apache-2.2, python, httpd, fedora, mod-wsgi

I tried to configure [Socorro](https://github.com/mozilla/socorro) server with apache [as described here](https://github.com/mozilla/socorro/blob/master/docs/prodinstall.rst).
I started httpd, but when I contact it with browser it doesn't respond. In lynx I get: `HTTP request sent; waiting for response.`

When I remove `crash-reports.conf`, `crash-stats.conf` and `socorro-api.conf` from `/etc/httpd/conf.d` httpd starts to response but ofc soccorro doesn't work.

In `/var/log/httpd/error_log` there is

```
ImportError: No module named site
ImportError: No module named site
ImportError: No module named site
ImportError: No module named site
[Thu Sep 05 07:05:45.267607 2013] [:alert] [pid 25735] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=25735): Unable to change working directory to '/home/socorro'.
ImportError: No module named site
[Thu Sep 05 07:05:45.387679 2013] [:alert] [pid 25739] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=25739): Unable to change working directory to '/home/socorro'.
```

What did I wrong?